# How can I export multiple object instances in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, inversifyjs

I am building a library in TypeScript that is using a dependency injection system [(inversifyJS)](https://github.com/inversify) to construct itself and resolve dependencies internally.
The problem I have is - I want to expose multiple instances from the injection system to the consumers of the library.

Currently what I am trying to do is:

```
import kernel from "./src/inversify.config";
import EntityManager from './src/manager/entityManager.service';
import StorageService from './src/storage/storage.service';
import LanguageService from './src/language/language.service';

export { kernel.get<EntityManager>(EntityManager) as EntityManagerInstance };
export { kernel.get<EntityManager>(LanguageService) as LanguageServiceInstance };
export { kernel.get<EntityManager>(StorageService) as StorageServiceInstance };
```

A solution that I see is possible is to use a facade to export types and access them later:

```
import EntityManager from './src/manager/entityManager.service';
import StorageService from './src/storage/storage.service';
import LanguageService from './src/language/language.service';
import InjectionFacade from './utils/injection.facede';

export { EntityManager, LanguageService, StorageService, InjectiorFacade }; 
// Usage: 
// import {InjectionFacade, StorageService} from 'entity-manager';
// let injectionFacade: InjectionFacade = InjectionFacade.createAndResolve();
// let storageService: StorageService = injectionFacade.getStorageService();
```

But the problem with this is I have one more useless abstraction

Is there a way to implement this kind of solution without loosing type definitions and exporting ready-to-use objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use a multiple-declaration variable, e.g.

```
export const
    EntityManagerInstance = kernel.get<EntityManager>(EntityManager),
    LanguageServiceInstance = kernel.get<EntityManager>(LanguageService),
    StorageServiceInstance = kernel.get<EntityManager>(StorageService);
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I want (for better or worse)

Comment: A side note: Calling `kernel.get` many times is an indicator of a possible [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) `kernel.get` should only be used once at your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)